# SQL command to Insert a range of years into a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very new toSQL and am creating a basic database for a Car Dealership. I have a table "Years" that I need to hold a range of years (1950 - 2014).

Instead of

```
INSERT INTO 'Years' ('year') ("1950");
INSERT INTO 'Years' ('year') ("1951");
INSERT INTO 'Years' ('year') ("1952");
```

etc, etc...

Is there an easier way to populate the table?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with the `Years` table?

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the disscussing the necessity of such a table for your application the task of pre-populating tables on MySQL side can be solved in several ways.

**First** and fastest is to do it in one statement utilizing a tally(numbers) table that can be persisted in your db or generate it on the fly as in following example

```
INSERT INTO years (`year`)
SELECT 1950 + q.n - 1
  FROM
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n
) q 
 WHERE q.n <= 2014 - 1950 + 1
```

*The subquery generates a sequence of numbers from 1 to 100. If you need ranges that span more than 100 years then you can adjust it or if you do a lot such queries then you can substitute it with a persisted tally(numbers) table.*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5eb86/1)** demo

---

**Second** approach is to create a stored procedure that uses `LOOP` and uses prepared statement

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE populate_years(IN _start_year INT, IN _end_year INT)
BEGIN
  PREPARE stmt FROM 'INSERT INTO years (year) VALUES(?)';
  SET @y = _start_year;

  START TRANSACTION;
  WHILE @y <= _end_year DO
      EXECUTE stmt USING @y;
      SET @y = @y + 1;
  END WHILE;
  COMMIT;

  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04438/1)** demo

Comment: @user2813264 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 2):

You should rethink your code, you will never need a table like that... whatever you are doing with that table surely could be done without it.

If you still want to create the table you have to use a loop.

For example if you are using php:

```
for ($i = 1950; $i <= 2014; $i++){
    mysqli->query("INSERT INTO 'Years' ('year') (".$i.")");
}
```